# Error while printing a string from assembly code

Tags: assembly, x86-16, emu8086, real-mode

I'm new to assembly and the course that I follow uses *EMU8086*. I wrote this code to print `Testing` and the ASCII code of 50 which is number `2` but it only prints `Testing` and ignores the rest. What's wrong?

```
.model tiny
.code

org 100h


main proc

    mov ah, 09h
    mov dx, offset msg
    int 21h 
    mov ah, 4ch
    mov dx ,0  
    mov dl, 2
    add dl, 48
    int 21h      

endp

msg db "Testing$"

end main
```

After reading the comments from @500 - Internal Server Error, I updated my code to this:

```
.model tiny
.code

org 100h


main proc

    mov ah, 09h
    mov dx, offset msg
    int 21h 
    mov dl, 2
    add dl, 48
    int 21h      

endp

msg db "Testing$"

end main
```

It still isn't working, so what's wrong?

Comment: When ah = 4ch for int 21h, you are asking the program to exit - the value of dl is most likely completely ignored by that request.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError i removed this line of code and still not working

Comment: Update the question with what the code looks like now, then. Generally, you'll need another interrupt (ah=09h or another one) in order to output anything else. The `Testing$` string gets terminated by the `$`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *DOS* interrupt [*INT 21h/AH=9h*](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-2562.htm) doesn't take a character value to print, it takes the memory offset to the beginning of a `$` terminated string to print.

> DOS 1+ - WRITE STRING TO STANDARD OUTPUT
>
> AH = 09h
>
> DS:DX -> '$'-terminated string
>
> Return:
>
> AL = 24h (the '$' terminating the string, despite official docs which state that nothing is returned) (at least DOS 2.1-7.0 and NWDOS)

If you want to print out a single character with *INT 21h/AH=9h* then you'll need to move the value into a buffer that is terminated with a `$` sign. You then pass the address of that buffer into *INT 21h/AH=9h*. Based on your second example something like this should work:

```
.model tiny
.code
org 100h

main proc
    mov ah, 09h             ; DOS Interrupt ah=9h print $ terminated string
    mov dx, offset msg      ; Address of msg 
    int 21h                 ; Int 21h/ah=9h Print msg 
    mov outchar, 48+2       ; Move ASCII val for `2` to outchar buffer
    mov dx, offset outchar  ; Address of the $ terminated outchar buffer in DX
    int 21h                 ; AH is still 9h, so this prints $ terminated string

    mov ax, 4c00h           ; Exit program with return value 0
    int 21h    
endp

msg db "Testing$"           ; msg string
outchar db ?, "$"           ; output buffer for single character terminated with $

end main
```

Instead of `mov outchar, 48+2` you could just use the ASCII value like this:

```
mov outchar, '2'
```

---

Alternatively you could do it with a single call to *INT 21h/AH=9h* by placing the character you want into the middle of an output buffer:

```
main proc
    mov outchar, '2'    ; Place the ASCII value for '2' in the output buffer
    mov ah, 09h         
    mov dx, offset msg  
    int 21h             ; Print $ terminated string starting at `msg`
    mov ax, 4c00h
    int 21h             ; Exit with error code 0
endp

msg     db "Testing"
outchar db ?, "$"
```

The reason this works is because *INT 21h/AH=9h* will blindly print everything it finds starting at offset `msg` until it finds a `$` terminating character. We effectively do the substitution of the character at `outchar` first so that when *INT 21h/AH=9h* is executed it will encounter `Testing2$` in memory.

Once it reaches the `$` it will stop printing so the output would look like:

> Testing2

---

You also have the option of using two different DOS (INT 21h) interrupts. While *INT 21h/AH=9h* prints a `$` terminated string, [*INT 21h/AH=2h*](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-2554.htm) displays a single character:

> DOS 1+ - WRITE CHARACTER TO STANDARD OUTPUT
>
> AH = 02h
>
> DL = character to write
>
> Return:
>   AL = last character output (despite the official docs which state
>   nothing is returned) (at least DOS 2.1-7.0)

You could code your program to display the `msg` string as you did, but then you can use *INT 21h/AH=2h* to display a single character. Your code could then look like this:

```
.model tiny
.code
org 100h

main proc
    mov ah, 09h             ; DOS Interrupt ah=9h print $ terminated string
    mov dx, offset msg      ; Address of msg 
    int 21h                 ; Int 21h/ah=9h Print msg 
    mov ah, 02h             ; DOS interrupt ah=2h print single character
    mov dl, '2'             ; DL = ASCII value of character to print
    int 21h                 ; Int 21h/ah=2h print single character in DL 

    mov ax, 4c00h           ; Exit program with return value 0
    int 21h    
endp

msg db "Testing$"           ; msg string

end main
```

Answer (score 1):

Your second code is almost fine, you only forgot the service number in `ah` to tell `int 21h` what to do :

```
.model tiny
.code

org 100h


main proc

    mov ah, 09h
    mov dx, offset msg
    int 21h 

    mov ah, 2          ;<==== AH=2 : INT 21H WILL DISPLAY CHARACTER IN DL.
    mov dl, 2
    add dl, 48
    int 21h      

endp

msg db "Testing$"

end main
```